# existe alguma alternativa de um condicional gigante sem ser por switch case?

Tags: php, condição, switch

```
    $metodo = array(
        "1"=> fazMetodo1(), //retorna algum valor
        "2"=> fazMetodo2(), //retorna algum valor
        "3"=> fazMetodo3() //retorna algum valor
        //... assim vai
    );

    $inputId = "2";

    if (array_key_exists($inputId , $metodo )) {
        $metodo[$inputId]; 
    }


        //Por switch-case
        $inputId = "2";
        switch($inputId){
            case "1":
                fazMetodo1();
                break;
            case "2":
                fazMetodo2();
                break;
            case "3":
                fazMetodo3();
                break;
        }
```

o problema:
Assim que array iniciar, todos os métodos vão retornar alguma coisa, existe uma forma alternativa de fazer sem ser por switch case?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "condicional gigante"(falando em quantidades, claro)?

Comment: isso, se eu tiver um switch com muito cases, existe uma outra alternativa?

Comment: Explique melhor qual seu problema. A alternativa você já deu. Fora isso tem uma enorme gambiarra, então é melhor nem fazer.

Comment: pensei que havia uma alternativa melhor, o problema é que ele vai executar todos os métodos assim que array for iniciada (seria essa a gambiarra?), rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os elementos do `$inputId` representam a chave do array então use as variáveis como string, variáveis no php podem chamar funções, veja um exemplo:

```
$metodo = array(
    'fazMetodo1',
    'fazMetodo2',
    'fazMetodo3',
    'fazMetodo4'
);

if (isset($metodo[$inputId]) && is_callable($metodo[$inputId])) {
    $callback = $metodo[$inputId];
    $callback(); //Chama a função
}
```

Prefira usar `isset` e o `is_callable` ao `array_key_exists`, pois assim poderemos verificar se a variavel existe ou é `null` e o `is_callable` verifica se é "chamavel".